# REGEXP Date greater than or equal to today.

Tags: php, mysql, regex, date

I am trying to pull specific data from MYSQL table which contains a date field. The date field is not limited to just a date, it has data like (05/03/2014 8am-noon). I have created a query using REGEXP searching where date field contains today's date. It returns it just fine, however I want it to also return dates that are greater than today. How can I do that? This is what I have now, $date is a variable for today's date:

```
"SELECT *
 FROM REGISTERED2
 WHERE DATEONE REGEXP '$date or
       DATETWO REGEXP '$date' or
       DATETHREE REGEXP '$date' or
       DATEFOUR REGEXP '$date'";
```

Now I would like it to search for `WHERE DATEONE REGEXP >= '$date'` and so on. Is that posssible? If so, please let me know how. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use regular date fields (`DATE`, `DATETIME` etc) and use one for "beginning", one for "end"? Then you could use regular date logic in your query

Comment: What does $date equals? As above you would be better with using datetime column type, then you can search WHERE date BETWEEN '2012' AND '2014'

Comment: I've split them up as you've suggested; it was much easier this way. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a follow up; now that I have a date field in my table (named dt) and the text entered is formatted as mm/dd/yyyy, can use mysql to search WHERE dt >= date("m/d/Y") ?